# Should I use multi-project solution for Auth and Resource Server development?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, directory-structure, solution

I am setting up an auth and resource servers for the backend of an app. The Auth Server is an **ASP.NET Core Web Application**, whereas the Resource Server is an **ASP.NET Web API 2** project(due to a COM reference dependency).

I am not sure if it is correct to unite these projects under one solution or not. Actually, there is **no shared code** between the projects. But they need to be developed and maintained as a whole in order to process requests correctly.

I know that decoupling Auth and Resource server is a common strategy when developing **applications with a subscription-based pricing model**. What is the **best practice** in these situations? **Should I separate my solution into 2 solutions** or keep using the **multi-project solution structure**?

Answer (score 0):

That's purely an issue of convenience.  Projects can always be built independently even without the solution file.  In that sense a "solution" file is more like a workspace that just shows all the things you want to work on at the same time.  Having said that, there are some cases where the presence of a .sln file CAN screw up .NET Core builds (I literally had one situation where it would be build the wrong configuration for a dependent project until I deleted the sln file, and yes, all the dependencies/configurations in the sln file looked perfectly normal).  At any rate it's an easily reversible decision if you start finding issues.